# How is signalling disturbed in trophoblastic cancer cells?

Tags: cancer

[Trophoblastic cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestational_trophoblastic_disease) seems to be a form of growth that no longer responds to the neural signals which try to inhibit them. Can someone please explain whether experiments have been performed as to how exactly cancer cells manage to "shut off," these neural signals?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I edited your question so that it now includes a reference to the Wikipedia article of the disease. I also tried to make it more clear and changed the title accordingly. However, I am not sure what you meant by "trophoblastic hypothesis of cancer". As the only trophoblastic cancers I am aware of are GTD (see link) and they are very rare, I would doubt that this is a general hypothesis for the various cancer forms. Then again, all cancers are a form of growth (this is one of the defining characteristics for tumours), so I am not really sure what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: I just want to know why they dont respond to normal neural signals like other cells.

Comment: If that has already been discovered

Comment: @Lelouch have you done any research at all on the subject? Tumors don't respond to normal growth inhibition signals because they have been highly mutated. Please read up on cancer, what it is, and how it arises - it is *very* well known why tumors don't respond to inhibitory signaling. Also, the neural system doesn't carry growth or growth-inhibitory signals. A system of protein-based cytokines and growth factors does that, as well as hormones.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you provide a link on the topic? I would be grateful.